# How to let NSTableView auto deinit an be bound object when I remove a table column?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview, appkit

I have 4 `CMYK` objects be bound in `NSTableCellView`. 
I pressed `Remove Column` button to remove last table column(succeed). take a look `removeTableColumn` function in `ViewController Class`. But the `CMYK` object does not auto deinit. 
How to auto deinit be bound objects when i remove a table column?

[image]
[image]

- CMYK Class

```
@objcMembers class CMYK: NSObject {
    public var C = CMYK.Component(value: 10)
    public var M = CMYK.Component(value: 20)
    public var Y = CMYK.Component(value: 30)
    public var K = CMYK.Component(value: 40)
    
    deinit {
        print("\(self) \(#function)")
    }
}

extension CMYK {
    @objcMembers class Component: NSObject {
        public var value: Double = 0.0
        
        init(value: Double) {
            self.value = value
            super.init()
        }
    }
}
```

- View Controller

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var colors = [CMYK(), CMYK(), CMYK(), CMYK()]
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func removeTableColumn(_ sendeer: Any) {
        if let column = tableView.tableColumns.last {
            if let idx = tableView.tableColumns.firstIndex(of: column) {
                self.colors.remove(at: idx)
                self.tableView.removeTableColumn(column)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- NSTableViewDataSource

```
extension ViewController: NSTableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
        var obj: Any?
        if tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "1" {
            obj = colors[0]
        } else if tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "2" {
            obj = colors[1]
        } else if tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "3"  {
            obj = colors[2]
        } else if tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "4" {
            obj = colors[3]
        }
        return obj
    }
}
```

Comment: The `colors` property of your view controller is keeping it alive.

Comment: @Alexander thx, sorry I forget to remove color object in colors array. I updated removeTableColumn function. thx

Comment: This is a good opportunity to use the “memory graph debugger” (Google it) to see which references are keeping your objects alive

Comment: What does "How to let NSTableView auto deinit an be bound object when I remove a table column?" mean?

Comment: Is the numbers of rows always 1? Why do you use a `NSTableView` instead of a `NSGridView`, `NSCollectionView` or `NSStackView`?

Comment: It looks like a bug to me. The `NSTableCellView` isn't moved to the reuse queue and `objectValue` isn't set to `nil` when a column is removed.

Comment: @Willeke thx. It just an example. I got the same result. I try to disable cell view reuse. If it be disabled will cause performance issue. I don't have any idea.

Comment: Workaround: hide the column, reloadData, remove the column.